# RouteConfig and classes, why is the constructor required to need a service and router?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I have been working with some sample code in the Angular2 framework.  The Heroes sample, for example.  There is 1 thing I am currently not understanding.  What is the factor that says my constructor needs to be `Router, Service` or viceversa.

I currently understand why they are needed for `@RouteConfig` to work, and the Service for the calls, but what is the explicit factor in saying "Because of X, you need the constructor to be Router, Service"

Is it that the class implemented OnInit?  Is it that the class is referenced in the application component's RouteConfig?  What makes the order as such, could I just reverse it the other way around?

That last question, I determined was a no-go, if i had 1 compoennt defined as `Router,Service` while another was `Service, Router`

If someone can give me some insight as to why this needs to be set up this way and where the definitions come from, it would better help me understand the concepts of Angular 2 more.

If you can point me to important doc files for this, that would be amazing too so i can read more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a constructor like

```
constructor(private router:Router, private service:Service) {}
```

then you tell Angulars DI that a `Router` instance should be passed as first constructor parameter and a `Service` instance as the 2nd contructor parameter when Angular needs to create an instance of that class.

Angulars DI then looks up the providers in its injector tree and returns an instance from the injector that finds a matching provider.

For that to work the class needs to have a decorator like `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Pipe()`, or `@Inectable()` and it only works for instances created by Angular. If you use `new Service()` or `new Router()` you are on your own and need to acquire and pass the required constructor parameters explicitely.

Comment: So, for the service, it will look through the tree for a type "Service" to inject, and similarly for Router?  Im new for Angular2, and the more angular-esque design methodology, so i am just a bit fuzzy, but it sounds like there is a tree of A and a Tree of B, and then it will just look up and find one to place into your constructors?

Comment: The tree starts with `bootstrap()` and the providers passed there. For each component a child injector with it's own set of providers is created and for the children of this component as well, and so on, and so forth. So you get an injector tree that resembles your component tree. When DI needs to pass an instance to a component it starts looking in the injector for this component for a provider, if it finds one it returns and instance from this provider, otherwise it looks upwards until it finds an injector that has a provider registered for this type.